# Create numpy array start from 0 to 1 with increment 0.1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm studying in python. I want to create numpy array in python, start from 0 to 1 with increment 0.1. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
t=np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
print(t)
```

the result is

```
[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
```

But "1" is not include in array, how to include 1 in array? Does we manually adding 1 to array, or any other ways?

Comment: Look at `np.linspace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [np.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) documentation

> `arange(stop)`: Values are generated within the half-open interval
> `[0, stop)` (in other words, the interval including *start* but
> excluding *stop*).
>
> `arange(start, stop)`: Values are generated within the half-open interval `[start, stop)`.
>
> `arange(start, stop, step)` Values are generated within the half-open `interval [start, stop)`, with spacing between values given by
> `step`.

So, to include 1, just change the code to `np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)` (any value greater than 1 and less or equal with 1.1 would work)

```py
>>> np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

Comment: for fractional step like .1, `arange` suggests you use `linspace`

Answer (score 1):

Python has a convention where, when specifying a range, it will iterate over that range from the start value to *just before* the end value (e.g. `for x in range(0, 15)` will assign x every value from 0 to 14--not 15). In your case, you can solve that by either setting the middle parameter (which correlates to the end value the iterator will stop just before) to be just over 1 (e.g. 1.1), or by manually appending 1. to the end like you mentioned.